# If Rolle's theorem is applicable to $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$,then range of $\alpha$ is

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             x^{\alpha}\sin(\frac{1}{x})\sin\pi x  & ,x\ne 0 \\
             0 &,x=0 \\
             \end{array}
   \right.$
If Rolle's theorem is applicable to $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$,then range of $\alpha$ is
$(A)-\infty<\alpha<-1$
$(B)\alpha=1$
$(C)-1<\alpha<\infty$
$(D)\alpha\geq0$

---

Here $f(0)=0$....given
$f(1)=1^{\alpha}\sin(\frac{1}{1})\sin\pi=0$
The function is continuous and differentiable on $[0,1]$.I do not know how to find the range of $\alpha.$I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

For some values of $\alpha$, the function is not continuous at $0$. For example think what happens at $x \to 0$ if $\alpha$ is negative and very large in absolute value.

Think carefully for which values of $\alpha$ you can guarantee that the function goes to $0$ when $x$ does.